# SQL Row with youngest DateStamp from Subselect in a Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

On `Patient` could have one or more `PrmryDiagnosis`, there is also a `DateStamp` to every `Diagnosis` in the database. So I am trying to get out only the newest `PrmryDiagnosis` if there are more `PrmryDiagnosis` than one.

I already got a bunch of Left outer joins in my code, and this code snippet with the max-clause in the subquery does not join me the `Diagnosis` to my table! It selects the right one, but does not join me a new column Diagnosis! Please could u help me! Best Regards!

```
/*code snippets*/

SELECT di.DiagnosisCode,
       di.Description,
       di.DiagnosisType
       di.PatientSer
FROM dbo.Activity,dbo.ActivityInstance,dbo.ScheduledActivity sa 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Patient pa ON sa.PatientSer = pa.PatientSer 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Diagnosis di ON(sa.PatientSer = di.PatientSer AND   
                                    di.DiagnosisType='PrmryDiagnosis' AND
                                    di.ObjectStatus='Active' AND 
                                    di.DateStamp = (Select MAX(DateStamp) 
                                                    from Diagnosis 
                                                    where di.PatientSer = sa.PatientSer))                                                                                                       

WHERE 
    (YEAR(sa.ScheduledStartTime) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AND  
    (MONTH(sa.ScheduledStartTime) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AND  
    (DAY(sa.ScheduledStartTime) = DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (Mysql,oracel, mssql)?

Comment: Its a Microsoft SQL Server Database (SQLNCLI10(SNC 10.0 for SQLServer 2008))

Comment: that query has 2 Cartesian products (implied cross joins) of these 3 tables: dbo.Activity, dbo.ActivityInstance, dbo.ScheduledActivity

Comment: thats not my Problem, I joined 7 tables with Left outer joins.it worked out very well, also joining the 'PrmryDiagnosis' worked out. But if there are 2 PrmryDiagnosis for 1 Patient, I become 2 whole datarows for this one Patient, but I want in this case only 1 datarow joined with the youngest PrmryDiagnosis. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: do I have ideas, yes, see the row_number() suggestion, what I can't do is invent ways those 3 tables join... so I cannot produce the whole query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider use of row_number() as shown here to arrive at the "most recent record"

```
SELECT
      di.DiagnosisCode
    , di.Description
    , di.DiagnosisType
    , di.PatientSer
FROM (
            SELECT
                  DiagnosisCode
                , Description
                , DiagnosisType
                , PatientSer
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientSer
                                     ORDER BY DateStamp DESC) AS rn
            FROM dbo.Diagnosis
            WHERE DiagnosisType = 'PrmryDiagnosis'
                  AND ObjectStatus = 'Active'
      ) di
WHERE rn = 1;
```